# Issue getting decision variable to optimize properly in Pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, glpk, clp

I have a simple multi-period optimization problem I am working on using pyomo. The goal of the model is to determine which hours a power plant should be on or off based on the Spark Spread (Power Price - Gas Price * Heat Rate + Variable Costs) for that hour. The Spark spread can be negative, which would indicate that the plant should be off, or positive which means the plant should be running.

Currently the results are a showing that the plant just gets turned on and runs despite the spark spread being negative.

How can I get the plant to turn on and off at each time step, given the spark spread for that hour?

I am sure this is a fairly simple solution, but I am very new to pyomo and optimization problems, so any guidance and help would be much appreciated.

```
gas_price = [2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81]
power_price = [26.24,23.8,21.94,20.4,21.2,19.98,19.34,18.83,19.19,18.48,21,21.77,23.45,26.53,29.85,31.8,28.7]

priceDict = dict(enumerate(power_price))
gasDict = dict(enumerate(gas_price))

m = en.ConcreteModel()

m.Time = en.RangeSet(0, len(power_price)-1)
m.powerPrice = en.Param(m.Time, initialize=priceDict)
m.gasPrice = en.Param(m.Time, initialize=gasDict)

m.generation = en.Var(m.Time, bounds=(0,800),
initialize=0)
m.spark = en.Var(m.Time,initialize=0)
m.heatRate = en.Var(m.Time,initialize=7)
m.vom = en.Var(m.Time,initialize=2)

m.max_gen = en.Param(initialize=800)


def Obj_fn(m):
    return sum((m.spark[i]*m.generation[i]) for i in m.Time)
m.total_cost = en.Objective(rule=Obj_fn,sense=en.maximize)

# 7 is the heat rate of the plant
def spark_rule(m,i):
    return (m.spark[i] == m.powerPrice[i]-(m.gasPrice[i]*7+m.vom[i]))
m.hourly_spark = en.Constraint(m.Time,rule=spark_rule)

def generation_rule(m,i):
    return (0<=m.generation[i]<=m.max_gen)
m.t_generation_rule = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=generation_rule)


opt = SolverFactory("clp",executable='C:\\clp.exe')
results = opt.solve(m)
```

The output of the model is currently:

```
Time Generation     Spark Spread
1   0               6.57
2   800             4.13
3   800             2.27
4   800             0.73
5   800             1.53
6   800             0.31
7   800            -0.33
8   800            -0.84
9   800            -0.48
10  800            -1.19
11  800             1.33
12  800             2.1
13  800             3.78
14  800             6.86
15  800            10.18
16  800            12.13
17  800             9.03
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, but don´t you want to optimize sum((max(m.spark[i, 0)]*m.generation[i]) for i in m.Time) so that when spark is negative the plant should not run -> not add generation?

Comment: Well the model should evaluate the spark spread at each time step and decide if the 'plant' should be generating in that hour or off in that hour. My thinking was that by maximizing the sum of  generation * spark spread, the optimization would decide when generation should be 0 or 800

Comment: Could you add the values of the current solution it is showing?

Comment: This looks like a nonconvex QP. They are not so easy to solve. You need a global solver for that. I believe CLP only supports convex QPs.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts @ErwinKalvelagen, I may try and reformulate the problem so I can use a solver such as GLPK/Clp.

Comment: Hi, are you sure `heatRate` and `vom` are meant to be variables and not parameters? In other words, are they fixed values (even though they might change through time), or are they part of the optimization problem?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I think you actually meant to define `heatRate` and `vom` as parameters, rather than variables.

This leads to a weird problem because the plant will naturally use its max power whenever the "spark" price is positive, and go to 0 whenever the spark price is negative. I guess you'll add more constraints later on.

If `heatRate` and `vom` are fixed, then you can redefine the problem in the following way:

```py
from pyomo import environ as pe

gas_price = [2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81,2.81]
power_price = [26.24,23.8,21.94,20.4,21.2,19.98,19.34,18.83,19.19,18.48,21,21.77,23.45,26.53,29.85,31.8,28.7]

priceDict = dict(enumerate(power_price))
gasDict = dict(enumerate(gas_price))

m = pe.ConcreteModel()

m.Time = pe.RangeSet(0, len(power_price)-1)

# this are all input parameters
m.powerPrice = pe.Param(m.Time, initialize=priceDict)
m.gasPrice = pe.Param(m.Time, initialize=gasDict)
m.vom = pe.Param(default=7)
m.heatRate = pe.Param(default=2)
m.maxGen = pe.Param(default=800)

# this is a "dependent" parameter
m.spark = pe.Param(m.Time,
    initialize = lambda m,t: m.powerPrice[t]-(m.gasPrice[t]*7+m.vom)
)

# this is the only variable
m.generation = pe.Var(m.Time, 
    initialize=0,
    bounds = (0, m.maxGen)
)

def Obj_fn(m):
    return sum((m.spark[t]*m.generation[t]) for t in m.Time)

m.total_cost = pe.Objective(rule=Obj_fn,sense=pe.maximize)
```